# multiple "AND" conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have situation where I needed to use three ***and*** conditions inside a JavaScript function.

I have written the code like this

```
    if (( frm_add_announcement.sublink[0].checked == true )) {
    if ((document.getElementById('captionurl').value.trim() == "") && 
    ( document.getElementById("captionfile").files.length == 0 ) && 
    (document.getElementById('ifpresent').value != "1")) {
    alert("Enter a url/upload a file");
    //var alertmsg=document.getElementById("captionfile").value;
    //alert(alertmsg);
    document.getElementById('captionurl').focus();
    return false;
    }
    }
```

But it doesn't work. There are no console errors

Comment: Does it give errors in the console?

Comment: You should check each condition one by one.

Comment: @KeesvanLierop-No..there is no error.

Comment: Try evaluating each condition separately to see if all of them are true. Like: `var c1 = document.getElementById('captionurl').value.trim()==""; console.log(c1);` etc.

Comment: Other than extra `()` in many places, and the fact that checking booleans with `==` is generally not best practice, that code is fine. (Re that latter: Just `if (thethingis.checked)` rather than `if ( (thethingis.checked == true ) )` (and for the not case: `if (!thethingis.checked)`)

Comment: Your browser has a powerful debugger built into it in the "development tools." To figure out what's wrong, use it to set a breakpoint on the first `if` above and then run the code. The debugger will stop at the breakpoint, allowing you to examine variables. You can then step through the code step-by-step.

Comment: I think you'd better test for each condition. "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us what its supposed to work out :)

Comment: We can better solve your problem if you put html code.

Comment: I only see two and conditions in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is OK and there is no error, but I see that you can make a refactor by creating variables and instead of doing 2 `if` statements you can do only one:

```
var captionurl = document.getElementById('captionurl'),
    captionfile = document.getElementById('captionfile'),
    ifpresent = document.getElementById('ifpresent');

if (frm_add_announcement.sublink[0].checked &&
    captionurl.value.trim() === '' &&
    captionfile.files.length === 0 &&
    ifpresent.value !== '1') {
    alert('Enter a url/upload a file');
    //var alertmsg=captionfile.value;
    //alert(alertmsg);
    captionurl.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Note that "But it doesn't work" do not express what is the spected result

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks to be syntactically fine. You need to call the `function` at the place where you need it in case you missed this part. The other possible problem is that you might need to check that you have a value in `captionurl`, the number of files is greater than 0 and the `ifpresent` value is 1. In that case, you need to have three or conditions:

```
if (( frm_add_announcement.sublink[0].checked == true )) {
    if ((document.getElementById('captionurl').value.trim() == "") || 
        ( document.getElementById("captionfile").files.length == 0 ) || 
        (document.getElementById('ifpresent').value != "1")) {
        alert("Enter a url/upload a file");
        //var alertmsg=document.getElementById("captionfile").value;
        //alert(alertmsg);
        document.getElementById('captionurl').focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also you might want to negate your first condition.